# xmonad: Check if a window is present in a workspace

Tags: haskell, xmonad

In this certain section of my `xmonad.hs` config:

```hs
changeWorkspaces f i z = do
                windows $ f i
                when (z == True && windowsPresent /= "0") $ notifyWS i
                    where notifyWS i = spawn ("notify-send \"hello, workspace: " ++ i ++ "\"") 

                          windowsPresent :: XState -> String
                          windowsPresent = show . length . W.index . windowset
```

And specifically in..

```hs
    when (z == True && windowsPresent /= "0") $ notifyWS i
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

..I'm trying to check to see if a window or any number of windows (`windowsPresent`) is present in a workspace. If there are, as well as if z is equal to True, then run `notifyWS`.

The code above is one of my many experiements to solve this problem, and I'm aware that it's just a shot in the dark.

I've read through [XMonad.StackSet](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.17.2/docs/XMonad-StackSet.html#v:member) and [XMonad.Operations](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.17.2/docs/XMonad-Operations.html), and I have a hard time understanding their usage. I've tried the functions [peek](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.17.2/docs/XMonad-StackSet.html#v:peek), [index](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.17.2/docs/XMonad-StackSet.html#v:index), and [member](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.17.2/docs/XMonad-StackSet.html#v:member), even looking through their source code, but getting them into boolean or arithmetic comparison is out of my limited knowledge for Haskell.

---

Provided error:

```
xmonad.hs:223:54: error:
    • Couldn't match type: [Char]
                     with: XState -> String
      Expected: XState -> String
        Actual: String
    • In the second argument of ‘(/=)’, namely ‘"0"’
      In the second argument of ‘(&&)’, namely ‘windowsPresent /= "0"’
      In the first argument of ‘when’, namely
        ‘(z == True && windowsPresent /= "0")’
    |
223 |                 when (z == True && windowsPresent /= "0") $ notifyWS i
    |
```

Code snippet:

```hs
    -- // workspace navigation
    -- mod-[1..9]         = Switch to workspace 
    -- mod-shift-[1..9]   = Move window to workspace
    -- mod-control-[1..9] = Move window to workspace and switch to that workspace
    [ ((modm .|. m, k), changeWorkspaces f i z)
        | (i, k) <- zip (myWorkspaces) [xK_1 .. xK_9]
        , (f, m, z) <- [ (W.greedyView, 0, False), 
                         (W.shift, shiftMask, True), 
                         (\i -> W.greedyView i . W.shift i, controlMask, True) ]
    ] 
        where 
            changeWorkspaces f i z = do
                windows $ f i
                when (z == True && windowsPresent /= "0") $ notifyWS i
                    where notifyWS i = spawn ("notify-send \"hello, workspace: " ++ i ++ "\"") 
 
                          windowsPresent :: XState -> String
                          windowsPresent = read . show . length . W.index . windowset
```

Comment: What error are you getting? It looks right to me (not idiomatic tho... but that's not a problem now) Also, may you add some descriptions about what `f`  `i` and `z` are meant to be?

Comment: @Ismor [Here's the error.](https://pastebin.com/UL80H5R6) For the values `f`, `i`, and `z`, these are just arguments coming from my keybindings in my xmonad config. They don't really effect my problem, as they have no part in the error. [Here's a snippet if you want to see.](https://pastebin.com/iUUsm7VG)

Comment: Please edit your question adding the relevant information. Do not link to external sources. Coming back to your problem: you are having a type problem, let me ask what you want is a function which returns true if any workspace has a window or if the workspace `i` has a window?

Comment: Apologies, question has now been edited. Anyway, that is basically what I want, but I'm having trouble with the `/= "0"` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I understood what you want. I haven't tested the solution (no Xmonad available now). Let me know if it works

```hs
-- You may need to import things

    [ ((modm .|. m, k), changeWorkspaces f i z)
        | (i, k) <- zip (myWorkspaces) [xK_1 .. xK_9]
        , (f, m, z) <- [ (W.greedyView, 0, False), 
                         (W.shift, shiftMask, True), 
                         (\i -> W.greedyView i . W.shift i, controlMask, True) ]
    ] 
        where 
            changeWorkspaces f i z = do
                windows $ f i
                stackset <- gets windowset  -- you need import Control.Monad.State.Class IIRC
                --   Just check for z and windowsPresent.
                when (z && windowsPresent stackset) $ notifyWS i
                    where notifyWS i = spawn ("notify-send \"hello, workspace: " ++ i ++ "\"") 
                          -- This should return True if workspace i has a windows
                          -- If workspace i doesn't exist; then checks if current
                          -- focused workspace has a window open
                          windowsPresent :: WindowSet -> Bool
                          windowsPresent = null . W.index . W.view i
```

EDIT: For the checking if the current workspace has a window, you can define the function `currentWorkSpaceHasWindow = isJust . peek`.

For example

```hs
-- You may need to import things

    [ ((modm .|. m, k), changeWorkspaces f i z)
        | (i, k) <- zip (myWorkspaces) [xK_1 .. xK_9]
        , (f, m, z) <- [ (W.greedyView, 0, False), 
                         (W.shift, shiftMask, True), 
                         (\i -> W.greedyView i . W.shift i, controlMask, True) ]
    ] 
        where 
            changeWorkspaces f i z = do
                windows $ f i
                stackset <- gets windowset  -- you need import Control.Monad.State.Class IIRC
                -- just move condition to its own line for clarity
                let cond = z && not (windowsPresent stackset) && currentWorkSpaceHasWindow stackset  
                when cond $ notifyWS i
                    where notifyWS i = spawn ("notify-send \"hello, workspace: " ++ i ++ "\"") 
                          -- This should return True if workspace i has a windows
                          -- If workspace i doesn't exist; then checks if current
                          -- focused workspace has a window open
                          windowsPresent :: WindowSet -> Bool
                          windowsPresent = null . W.index . W.view i
                          -- import Data.Maybe for isJust function.
                          -- True if the current ws has a window
                          currentWorkSpaceHasWindow :: WindowSet -> Bool
                          currentWorkSpaceHasWindow = isJust . peek
```

Comment: Thank you! Added `not` to `windowsPresent` of this code, and my problem is solved. If you don't mind me asking, what about checking only the currently focused workspace? For example, if the current workspace does not contain any windows, don't run `notifyWS`.

Comment: @Anapal added edition

Comment: @Ismor Hm, `currentWorkSpaceHasWindow` does not work in this code because as you shift/move the window to a workspace from the current one with the keybind, it checks **after** it shifts/moves the window, therefore the current workspace (assuming if there is only one window) does not have a window anymore, and the check returns false. Moving `windows $ f i` to below `when cond $ notifyWS i` fixes the issue. Again, thank you!